# Segue performs even though identifier is not met

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

i've created a segue form a uibutton to a viewController with the style push. I only want this segue to be pushed if a criteria is met. Therefor i've created an identifier like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSuccessful1" sender:self];
```

But it seems like that the segue is beeing pushed even though the performSegueWithIdentifier has not been called. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having the segue go directly from the button, hook up the UIButton to an IBAction on your view controller. Then, in this IBAction, check your condition and call your performSegue. When hooking a segue directly from a button, the ViewController is not consulted first.

Comment: Well where is the connection then? i need to give an identifier to something.

Comment: Like @codester states in his answer, it needs to be added between the two ViewControllers.

Comment: You can also implement the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` Method to potentially veto the segue but my preference is to change the button's enable state based on the criteria - this gives visual feedback that the button is inactive rather than leaving the user wondering why nothing is happening

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `segue` from button and connect it from `ViewController` to `AnotherViewController` as `pushsegue` not from `UIButton`

And check the condition and perform the `segue`

```
if(this == that){

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSuccessful1" sender:self];
}
```